# How can we migrate Data with MySQL 5.1 - MyISAM to another server with MySQL 5.6 - InnoDB

Tags: innodb, mysql-5.6, migration, myisam, mysql-5.1

Currently we have a MySQL 5.1 - MyISAM database on a physical server. We need to move it to another server with MySQL 5.6 - InnoDB at another location.

DB size is quite large - 210GB

Can someone help - how can we acheive this.

We appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Pasting your question into the Google search field might be a good start.

Comment: Already tried Google Search. No meaningful answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you do is to

a) take a mysqldump of your database:

`mysqldump --user my_user --password=<pass> --host=my_db schema_name > my_schema.sql`

b) then use a tool such as sed to substitute MyISAM for InnoDB:

`sed -i 's/ENGINE=MyISAM/ENGINE=InnoDB/g'  my_schema.sql`

c) restore the dump on your 5.6 instance:

`mysql --user=my_user --password=<pass> my_schema < my_schema.sql`

If you're on Windows, you can use vim for Windows or the editing tool of your choice.

You might be better off using a command like

`sed 's/ENGINE=MyISAM/ENGINE=InnoDB/g'  my_schema.sql > my_schema2.sql`

or take a backup of your .sql file - with 260 GB, you never know what can go wrong - from the sed manpage

> when in-place editing files, as you risk corruption or partial content
>   in situ- ations where disk space is exhausted, etc.